# Plotting circles with complex numbers

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

How do I plot this circle ? what does it look like

radius 3 and centre 3/i ?

Comment: Well, $3/i = 3\cdot \frac{1}{i}$, and $\frac{1}{i} = -i$, so it looks like a radius 3 circle centered at $(0,-3i)$.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that a circle centered in the origin, with radius $r$ can be parametrized by $\alpha (t) = r e^{it}$, with $t \in [0, 2 \pi [$.
Then you only have to move this to $(0, -3i)$ by a translation.